# Combo box selected item null and not displaying DB value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a combobox `cboPrePartNum` with:

- Data Source  - prepartBindingSource
- Display Member - PrePartNum
- Value Member - PrePartNum
- Selected Value - engordbindingsource - prepartnum

When the form loads this is run:

```c#
private void LoadComboBoxes()
{
    List<PartPrevious> partPreviousList;
    partPreviousList = PartDB.GetPartPreviousList();
    cboPrePartNum.DataSource = partPreviousList;
    cboPrePartNum.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Problem is when the form loads the `cboPrePartNum` combobox does not display the value currently in `engordbindingsource.prepartnum`.

This is what PartPrevious looks like:

```c#
public class PartPrevious
{
    private string prepartnum;
    private string prerevision;
    private string prepartdescription;

    public PartPrevious() { }

    public string PrePartNum
    {
        get { return prepartnum; }
        set { prepartnum = value; }
    }

    public string PreRevision
    {
        get { return prerevision; }
        set { prerevision = value; }
    }

    public string PrePartdescription
    {
        get { return prepartdescription; }
        set { prepartdescription = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `PartPrevious` look like? Your combobox doesn't show correctly so what does it show?

Comment: the combo box has a list of values, but it is supposed to show the value in engordbindingsource.prepartnum

Comment: your question is unclear, you should provide some values from your list, and some values your combobox showed and also your definition of the class `PartPrevious`

Comment: I can see that your `PartPrevious` doesn't have any `PartNum` property, so how could your combobox display correctly?

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say PrePartNum

Comment: for example engordbindingsource.prepartnum = "00044XXX" in the database, this should be the value selected in the cboPrePartNum when the form loads.

Comment: define display value and key value in fillcombo box

Comment: If you need to display the underlying data via the combobox, you have to add some `Binding` which I doesn't see in your code. Your combobox is just initialized with DataSource and defined for how it should show the data (if have any bound to it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U should set

```
cboPrePartNum.DataTextField
```

and `cboPrePartNum.DataValueField`

Then it will binds correctly

Comment: if I set the SelectedText property, then my combo box displays the db value.  However, when you click on the drop down that value is not selected in the list.  How can I get this value selected?

Comment: I had to Trim the data before assigning to the combo box.  Working now.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set the Selected Value in the combo box. You can get and set the selected item like in following code,

```
 cboPrePartNum.SelectedItem = <PartPrevioustype of object>;

 <PartPrevioustype of object> = cboPrePartNum.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: cboPrePartNum.SelectedItem = CustomData.Part;